# Converting JSON string to UIImage

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage

I'm looking for an example of how I can display a specific UIImage (held in Asset catalog) based on what string is passed from the JSON response.

E.g. if the database_field has "Balloons" selected, it won't display the word "Balloons" but convert it to display the image "Balloons".
I have tried using `switch` and `case` to change the String to an image but get all sorts of compilation errors.

EDIT

What I was looking for, and what I couldn't get working (because I'm new to `switch`...!) was the following code:

```
        if let imgType = bug.bugType {

        var imgTypeImageName = ""
        switch imgType {
        case "Ballons":
            imgTypeImageName = "Balloons"
            break
        case "Apple":
            imgTypeImageName = "Apple"
            break
        default:
            imgTypeImageName = "default"
            break
        }

        imgIconImage.image = UIImage(named: imgTypeImageName)
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [initializer for UIImage that accepts a string for the image name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-init).  Here is an example playground.  You need to drag in test.jpg into the Resources folder on the left hand side for this playground to run correctly.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let jsonData = """
{
"imageName" : "test.jpg"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct CustomStruct: Codable {
    let imageName: String
    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}

let custom = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CustomStruct.self, from: jsonData)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
imageView.image = custom.image
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```